# Is there a way to zoom in/out (not scale) on a TKinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-turtle

I am procedurally generating an image using turtle. I use the following code to keep the image in full view. However, after scaling out, I can't position the turtle correctly to continue generating the image. I'm not sure if my math is wrong, logic is wrong, or I'm using the wrong tools for the job. Any help is appreciated.

```
i_width = round(x_max - x_min)  # x_max, x_min, y_max, y_min are max and min coordinates reached by turtle so far
i_height = round(y_max - y_min) # i_height, i_width are size of generated image
scale_x, scale_y = 1, 1
if i_width > c_width:           # c_height, c_ width are size of tkinter window
    scale_x = round(c_width/i_width, 1)
if i_height > c_height:
    scale_y = round(c_height/i_height, 1)
scale = scale_x if scale_x <= scale_y else scale_y  # so that aspect ratio is maintained
if scale != 1:
    canvas.scale('all', 0, 0, scale, scale)
    # update size of image
    x_min *= scale
    x_max *= scale
    y_min *= scale
    x_max *= scale
    t_scale *= scale    # track total scaling so far. used so further image generation is not a different size

    # move turtle in order to continue where it left off. image has been scaled but turtle is still at original coordinates
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x_curr*scale, y_curr*scale) # I feel this is where I'm going wrong
    turtle.pendown()
```

Now obviously, if I could zoom in/out of the canvas without scaling the image, then my problem is solved since the image itself won't change wrt to the coordinates grid. Is that a possibility?

Comment: This could use a [mcve].